# Get an Integer value from 4 consecutive bytes in a string

Tags: c

Being given a char array, I have to save in a variable of type int a number that is represented on 4 consecutive bytes in that char array. 
I know the position where the first byte is in that array. 
What should I do?

Edit: 
Solution #1:

```
 int number , offset;
 char *data;
 memcpy(&number, &data[offset], 4);
```

Solution #2:

```
 int number , offset;
 char *data;
 number = *(int*)(data + offset);
 // offset: where the first of the four bytes is situated
```

Comment: You can `memcpy()` the 4 bytes into a 4-byte `int` variable, though depending on endian you may or may not have to swap the bytes. Or, you could just bit-shift the individual 4 bytes into the `int` in the desired order

Comment: @RemyLebeau looking at the title I would gather that those `char` are actually ASCII representations of digits, like `{'4', '3', '1', '7'}`. OP, can you please clarify?

Comment: you need to paste the code you tried.  otherwise it is off topic.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca could be four unsigned chars and this is perfectly good to be transformed into an integer. Byte shifting into a 4-byte integer will be OK. Also using an union, but this is not always a good practice.

Comment: @GovindParmar I know and use it, but some complain about portability, so...

Comment: @yoan yes, unless they want 4317 as a result (given the example in my previous comment)

Comment: @alinsoar: No, it is not. The guideline for closing as off-topic for lack of an MCVE is for questions asking “What is wrong with this code?” There is no general requirement that other types of questions provide “the code you tried.” It is appropriate to some questions and not needed for some questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem.

Comment: @SteveAtreides please post your solution as an answer, so others can benefit.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, also allowing to know if ascii codes or not. It is sad OP ask for answer but do not answer when we have question ....

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually, bit-shifting the individual bytes is not a proper solution. Left shifting a negative value, or a positive value whose mathematical result is not representable, is not defined by the C standard, so negative `int` values cannot be portably constructed solely by shifting bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried to do. It was correct, but I had a wrong offset and I thought the method was wrong. Using memcpy, I got the same result, so I knew which was the problem.

```
 int number , offset;
 char *data;
 number = *(int*)(data + offset);
 // offset: where the first of the four bytes is situated
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested

```
int convert_to_int(chat *buff, int ascii, int str, int endianess)
{
    union
    {
        int i;
        unsigned char uc[sizeof(int)];
    }ui = {.i = 0};
    int mult = 1;

    if(str)
    {
        for(int digit = 0; digit < sizeof(ui.i); digit++)
        {
            mult *= 10;
        }
    }

    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(int); index++)
    {
        size_t pos = endianess ? index : sizeof(ui.i) - 1 - index;

        if(str)
        {
            ui.i += mul * (*buff++ - '0');
            mul /= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            ui[pos] = ascii ? *buff++ - '0' : *buff++;
        }
    }
    return ui.i;
}
```

Comment: if it is the string "2345" it is 2 * 1000 3 * 100 etc

Comment: it is not plus and you need to multiply then add to the result 4 tumes. as it converts string to int.